# C# deserialization of System.Type throws for a type from a loaded assembly

Tags: c#, serialization, prism, system.type

I have an application `a.exe` which is running fine and has loaded an assembly `b.dll`, which is a Prism module if that matters. This dll is loaded from a directory that is not in the path but is in the directory where `a.exe` resides.

Loading of the assembly is done by Prism, and is set up like this:

```
public class MyModuleCatalog : ComposablePartCatalog
{
  private readonly AggregateCatalog _catalog;

  public MyModuleCatalog()
  {
      //directory Modules is not in the path, but all
      //dependencies of b.dll are, so b.dll gets loaded fine
    var asmCat = new AssemblyCatalog( "Modules/b.dll" );
    _catalog.Catalogs.Add( asmCat );
  }

  public override IQueryable<ComposablePartDefinition> Parts
  {
    get { return _catalog.Parts; }
  }
}

class BootStrapper : MefBootstrapper
{
  ....
  protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
  {
    base.ConfigureAggregateCatalog();

    AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add( new AssemblyCatalog( Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() ) );
    AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add( new MyModuleCatalog() );
  }
  ....
}
```

In `b.dll` there is a class `ImInB`:

```
[Export]
public class ImInB
{
  public void DoIt()
  {
    try
    {
      var stream = new MemoryStream();
      //using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.
      var formatter = new BinaryBinaryFormatter();

        //serialize our type
      formatter.Serialize( stream, this.GetType() );

        //get it back
      stream.Position = 0;
      var obj = formatter.Deserialize( stream ); //this throws??
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
    }
  }
}
```

This is just example code, and is part of a persisting framework that loads/saves settings to a database. The object's type is always serialized and serves as akey to the database. Upon deserializing, the type is retrieved back as a double check against the object that gets loaded.
The function gets called from `a.exe`:

```
container.GetExportedValue<ImInB>().DoIt();
```

The exception thrown upon deserializing the type (whih was serialized sucessfully two lines earlier) is:

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'b.dll, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
```

Questions:

- How is this even possible? The function gets called from within the dll, yet is says it cannot find that dll.
- How do I fix this? How do I tell `Deserialize` *hey, that dll is already loaded, don't go looking for it*

**UPDATE**
my second question is basically answered by Felix K; the following code fixes the problem:

```
public static class AssemblyResolverFix
{
  //Looks up the assembly in the set of currently loaded assemblies,
  //and returns it if the name matches. Else returns null.
  public static Assembly HandleAssemblyResolve( object sender, ResolveEventArgs args )
  {
    foreach( var ass in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() )
      if( ass.FullName == args.Name )
        return ass;
    return null;
  }
}

//in main
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += AssemblyResolverFix.HandleAssemblyResolve;
```

This also proves that the assembly is effectively loaded, including all of it's dependencies, so the first question remains: it's a mistery to me why the framework cannot figure this out by itself. Moreover I cannot reproduce it in a second application that uses roughly the same structure.

Comment: what are the name spaces of both the files.. perhaps you could change them to match and at the project level with your using.. the compiler would know how to reference it otherwise it sounds like you may need to use fully qualified namespaces for the methods it's can't or is suppose to find..

Comment: Does this d.dll depends on some other assembly as well? When loading via reflection all assembly static reference needs to be satisfied.

Comment: @DJKRAZE what files do you mean? all code in question is in one single class, in one single namespace. Though off course a.exe has different namespaces then b.dll

Comment: @zenwalker yes b.dll depends on other assemblies, but all of them are loaded (how else could the code be running?)

Comment: you can name your assemblies within same projects to match.. as long as the method names are not conflicting otherwise you would have to fully qualify them..

Comment: Using Assembly.LoadFile() is the common mistake.

Comment: @DJKRAZE sorry, I don't understand: afaik there is nothing to fully qualify here?

Comment: @HansPassant: do you mean that Prism uses Assembly.LoadFile() somewhere and that is causing this problem?

Comment: I assumed you used it.  No idea, you didn't post any relevant code.  Use fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems.

Comment: What does formatter.Serialize do?  That could be where the problem lies and why are you trying to deserialise a class that you are already in, if you need a reference to it just use this?  Are you trying to copy it?

Comment: I was wanting to see the namespace of public class ImInB  but not a problem sounds like there may be an issue with Loading the Assembly in his code

Comment: `or one of its dependencies` is the cause of problem IMHO,debugging the application and looking into call stack and local and auto variables could help you a lot.

Comment: @Jani it's not that, it's `The system cannot find the file specified`. It cannot be dependencies, as the dll is already loaded including all of it's dependencies. See solution in Felix K's answer.

Comment: I maybe wrong, but formatter.Serialize(stream, this.GetType()); serializes the **Type**, not the object itself, is it really what you want to do?

Comment: @SimonMourier yes that is *exactly* what I want to do

Comment: @stijn - ok, that's a strange way to do it. Just write the this.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName string if you need the full name with assembly name. Upon deserialization, obj will contain this same string.

Comment: @SimonMourier but I do need the actual Type to compare it against a list of known types; or can I convert AssemblyQualifiedName into a type? If so you sould post this as an answer as it's a nice trick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why this happens when the dll is already loaded but i think this has nothing to do with the serialization itself, it looks like a .NET error to me.

This might gonna help you, or points you in the right direction:

```
AppDomain current = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
current.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(HandleAssemblyResolve);

static Assembly HandleAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    /* Load the assembly specified in 'args' here and return it, 
       if the assembly is already loaded you can return it here */
}
```

Everytime when a dll is missing the resolve method is called, so this should also happen when your dll is missing. dotNET can't find it because it's in the "Modules" folder so you have to resolve the reference by yourself.

Comment: +1 this actually solves it. Within HandleAssemblyResolve I just loop over loaded assemblies and return the one where Assembly.FullName matches ResolveEventArgs.Name. Since it's this simple, I wonder why the framework cannot do it by itself.

Comment: @stijn Thats of course a good a good question. You should fill a bug report, maybe you get a answer then.

Comment: see my comment on x0n's answer: it's not really a bug, though it certainly is disturbing

Answer (score 1):

Type identity is a fickle thing. These two blog posts from the inimitable Suzanne Cook really cleared it up for me a few years ago:

LoadFile vs LoadFrom: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/09/19/loadfile-vs-loadfrom.aspx
Choosing a Binding Context: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57143.aspx

Comment: +bounty, this helped me figure out why this happens, sort of, with help of reflector. During deserialization of a type, plain Load is called but likely not in the same context as where the assembly was loaded initially in AssemblyCatalog (which also uses plain Load). Under the disadvantages of Load is mentioned 'Dependencies in other contexts are not available unless you subscribe to the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event'

Comment: @stijn thanks for the bounty, I'd give half to Suzanne but I don't think she works on the CLR team anymore :)